# msgraph powershell filtering variable

Tags: powershell, intune, microsoft-graph-api

i'm trying to get devices where the IMEI matches to the IMEI's in my list.

The variable $item does have a value, but this command doesn't show me any result

```
Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "imei eq '$item'" | Get-MSGraphAllPages
```

if i'm checking instead of the variables with the actual value, it gives me a return

```
Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "imei eq '123456789'" | Get-MSGraphAllPages
```

i'm importing the values from a csv file

Comment: Hi , could you please provide me the headers for csv file? after that we will help you with the correct query .

Answer (score 0):

If the header is imei, you can try with
Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "imei eq '$($item.imei)'" | Get-MSGraphAllPage

Hope this help , please let us know if you have any query

Thanks